# How to wait for a function to return a value before assigning it to a variable in javascript/mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Please look at my Mocha test:

```
it.only('verify Lot in CFR List',function(done)){
this.timeout(20000);
var data = ui.cfrVerifyLot(); //calling cfrVerifyLot() method from another file
data.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // 'getting undefined' 'expecting success or failed'
  if(result=='success'){
    done();
  }
});
}
```

It seems that ui.cfrVerifyLot() method is assigning returned valued before finishing itself.
How can make it wait to assign the result before it gets finished completely.

This is my cfrVerifyLot() function:

```
cfrVerifyLot:function(){

    var result = '';
    const rest = require('./restAPI');
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const assert = require('chai').assert;
    const cfg = require('../config-env.json');
    const objR = require('../obj-repo/obj-c.json');
    puppeteer.launch({
    //headless:false
}).then(async browser => {

    /*
    making some UI navigations
    */
    try{
    const innerText = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('some element name')[1].innerText);
    var str = innerText.substring(0,8);
    await page.waitFor(2*1000);
    if(str===input_lot_number){
      result = 'success'
      }          
    }
    catch(err){
      result = 'failed'  
    }
    finally{
      await browser.close();
      return result
    }
    });
},
```

Comment: use the `async` `await`

Comment: i have updated my answer. check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `async` and `await` operators.

```
 it.only('verify Lot in CFR List',async function(done)){
    this.timeout(20000);
    var result = await ui.cfrVerifyLot();
      console.log(result); // 'getting undefined' 'expecting success or failed'
      if(result=='success'){
        done();
      }
    });
    }
```

**EDIT**
Your `cfrVerifyLot` function `returns` no value. instead the `result` is returned from the `pupperteer`. Change the `puperteer's` then chain to use `await` so you return the `result` value directly from the function.

```
cfrVerifyLot:async function(){

    var result = '';
    const rest = require('./restAPI');
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const assert = require('chai').assert;
    const cfg = require('../config-env.json');
    const objR = require('../obj-repo/obj-c.json');
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({//headless:false})
     /*
    making some UI navigations
    */
    try{
    const innerText = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('some element name')[1].innerText);
    var str = innerText.substring(0,8);
    await page.waitFor(2*1000);
    if(str===input_lot_number){
      result = 'success'
      }          
    }
    catch(err){
      result = 'failed'  
    }
    finally{
      await browser.close();
      return result
    }  
},
```

Comment: Actually I tried it earlier. But when I use await keyword, it throws 'Unexpected identifier' as var result = await ui.cfrVerifyLot()
                                                                     ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: because there was no `async` before the function

Comment: I tried exactly as Norris has wrote, but I get the above error.

Comment: what version of node do you have installed

Comment: I am currently on node v8.9.1

Comment: are you sure you did `async function(done)){`. Preferably copy and paste the whole code

Comment: I copied pasted from your code. syntax error resolved but still getting undefined. as result. And this get printed way before that this function executed completely. This function is actually a UI validation so it takes time to gets finished.

Comment: paste the code for `ui.cfrVerifyLot();` in your question

Comment: It worked after I changed my cfrVerifyLot as per your recommendations. Thanks you so much Norris Oduro.

Comment: You should consider marking the answer if it was helpful. Thanks